# ¿Como obtener el Indice de un vector en C#?

Tags: c#, array

Quisiera saber como obtengo el indice de mi vector actual a través de c#, ya tengo una estructura en código pero ahí obtengo el valor de dicho indice y yo no quiero eso, sino que quiero obtener su indice para saber si va a realizar o no cierta acción.

Aqui esta mi codigo

```
for (int x = 0; x < c;x++ )
            {
                vector[x]=c2;
                if (vector[x]==0) {
                }
                else if (vector[x] !=0)
                {

                    if (vector[x] > vector[x+1])
                    {
                        mayor3 = vector[x];

                    }

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haya algunas variables que no se de donde salen como es el caso de `c2` o `mayor3`, pero si quieres tener el indice podrias simplemente asignarlo a una variable, como ser

```
int indice = 0;

for (int x = 0; x < c;x++ )
{
    vector[x]=c2;
    if (vector[x] != 0)
    {
        if (vector[x] > vector[x+1])
        {
            mayor3 = vector[x];
            indice = x;
        }

    }
}
```

de esta forma cuando se asigna el valor de resultado tambien lo haces del indice del vector asignando la `x`